# Get alarm time set in Clock app from another app in objective c using IOS sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, clock, app-store

How to get alarm time set in default Clock app available in iPhone programatically inside another iphone application. I have found someone say that CFPreferences api can be used but cannot find the exact way of using it to get alarm time from Clock app. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's no straightforward solution to what you're looking for. Regarding CFPreferences API, you'll first need to know how the Clock app stores the alarm information, or even if it does use the Preferences to store the alarm details in the first place. Once you figure this out then only you could use the CFPreferences API to achieve what you want.