# How to get clock alarm information on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to get the clock's alarm information on iOS, is there any way to fetch the information?

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow! Can you please tell us what have you tried and which tools you can use?

Comment: i don't which tool or method i could try to get the information.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026105/get-alarm-time-set-in-clock-app-from-another-app-in-objective-c-using-ios-sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way to do that.

I don't know how I can add credibility to my answer, except from saying that in iOS, apps are "sandboxed", so they don't "talk" with each other. The only way they can interact (in a **very** restricted way) is if they share a part of their App ID. As the stock clock app is made by Apple, there's no way your app will ever have access to data from the stock apps.

Comment: I had typed my own anser saying the same thing .. but now I just add: yip :D

Comment: is there any method to hack this?

Comment: There may be a way using jailbreak, but I can't be sure and have strictly no idea on how you could do that.

Comment: thanks,for now there's no way to access the clock's info...